# Jacob Schulthess Wangen an der Aare records

Tags: birth-records, death-records, switzerland, criminal-records

I'm just getting started researching my husband's family who came from Wangen an der Aare, Bern Canton, Switzerland.  I'm looking for Jacob Schulthess birth record who was born 29 Jan 1892 in Wangen an der Aare.

We are told Jacob's father, also named Jacob died in prison at Wangen an der Aare sometime between 1894 and 1899.  He accidentally shot his mother in law with a gun, intending to shoot his wife who had been unfaithful to him.  Ha! I'd like to know the date of Jacob Schulthess Sr.'s death.  Would there be court records of his trial?

The unfaithful wife was Emma Obrecht born 20 Dec 1869 in Wangenreid, Bern. She eimgigrated to US in 1901 and settled in Monroe, Wisconsin.

Comment: There seem to be two questions in here -- one about birth records for an individual, and one about the death/court records associated with anothr individual or individuals. Can you split it into two better-defined questions, so that it gets better responses.

Comment: To split your question just do a copy/paste of your question content into a new question and then revise each to focus on one of the two more specific questions.  It is fine to include a link to the other in each as background if you wish.

Comment: Just for future reference the intention of my comment was for you to create one additional question, and to [edit] this one to reduce this one to being just a single question.  Let's leave things the way they are now and proceed with the two new questions that you have created.